# DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user at RequestHandler.execute

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hey so i made a 'hack' command in my bot as a joke, i want it to dm the author of the message, but whenever i run the command, it just gives me a error, even if the author has open dm's. this is the error:

DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user

And this is my code:

```
msg.author.send(`Name:${taggedUser.username},
             ID:${taggedUser.id}
             IP Address:${response}`).catch(console.error)

        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for this particular error to originate apart from the member being either unavailable to the client or has direct messages closed you can simply tweak your code a little so if the dms are closed it would post to the channel instead like so:

```js
msg.author.send(`Name:${taggedUser.username},
             ID:${taggedUser.id}
             IP Address:${response}`).catch(() => {
    msg.channel.send(`Unable to Direct Message user instead sending this here!\n\n Name:${taggedUser.username},
             ID:${taggedUser.id}
             IP Address:${response}`)
    });
```

### Sources:

- **Discord.js' Role**:  
  [discordjs/discord.js/src/rest/DiscordAPIError.js](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/cfde127072ae06b63f17ba19b3e0d28fddef97d6/src/rest/DiscordAPIError.js)

   This just extends the error thrown by discord API in case of explicit faliure so has no hand in the error.
- **Discord's Role:** 
  [Documentation reference of error messages](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#error-messages)

   This throws the specific error and you know, Discord itself can't be wrong or else stackoverflow would be flooded with similar questions and bots would break haha!